# Visual Basic 2010 crashes when clicking in specific subroutine

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

When clicking in a specific subroutine in Visual Basic 2010, the application crashes giving only the error message "Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 [Express] has encountered a problem and needs to close."

Nothing appears in the log and safe mode doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had this problem, I found it was due to a line continuation over 400 lines.

For example:

```
Dim someString As String
someString = "some text and then a line continuation " & _
             "and then some more text for 400 lines " & _
             ... & _
             "and then finish the string"
```

To fix it, I just had to make my code a little sloppier by combining multiple "lines" on one line.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are clicking on a module or a .vb file in the solution space.  Try right clicking, then "edit code" if at all possible.  If there is an Interop object, perhaps a control (.OCX) that not's registered ion Windows, then VS will crash -- promise!

Comment: This was a Q&A style post - I was just sharing the experience I had with an error.